# Как хранить сюжетную линию игры?

Tags: php, sql

Как хранить сюжетную линию, если она представляет вот такое дерево: [image: Дерево состояний в игре]

С чего начать? Как готовить сценарий? Как идти по нему? Нумеровать и сохранять позицию (saved_pos+1)? Как в таком случае обыгрывать переход на какую-то из веток?

Comment: Обычный направленный граф. И соответствующие методы хранения. Ну и антураж в отдельной таблице со ссылкой на узел.

Answer (score 1):

Весь список состояний хранить в одной таблице. `id, description`
Для хранения стрелочек есть варианты. Например:
Таблица переходов `from_id, to_id`

---

**Как идти**

1.Выбираем стартовое состояние:

```
SELECT * FROM State s
JOIN Transitions t on t.to_id = s.id
WHERE t.from_id is null
```

2.Выбираем список дальнейших вариантов:

```
SELECT * FROM State s
JOIN Transitions t on t.to_id = s.id
WHERE t.from_id = :current
```

3.Повторяем пункт 2, пока не будет выбран вариант с `to_id = null`.
Конец.